# IMPORTRANGE values become error if sheet is otherwise modified

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a shared spreadsheet with names/dates. I want to import my bit of this to my Google Calendar, so I use `IMPORTRANGE(.......  )` to write the data to a new sheet 'justforme', which updates with any changes to the shared sheet without having to delete and re-enter  IMPORTRANGE.

But if my calendar script writes anything to the 'justforme'  sheet ( eg calendar entry ID), using `range.setValue()`, the import range date changes to #REF.

Any way round this, other than get the script to delete and re-enter the `IMPORTRANGE`  statement ?

Comment: Reevaluate your layout.

Comment: Expanding on what @tehhowch said, `importrange` writes an array of data from one location to another location, and breaks if any cell in the second location is edited.  If you want to add or change data, it either needs to be done in the original location, or outside the range imported in the second location.